# What is correct? My son is studying Electrical engineering or my son is pursuing Electrical engineering

Tags: differences

What is correct?
My son is studying Electrical engineering.
or
My son is pursuing Electrical engineering.

Comment: It's not really a matter of "correct". But whereas you ***study*** a ***subject***, you'd usually metaphorically ***pursue*** something like a ***career***.

Comment: In Philadelphia, most people say ``My son is into Electrical Engineering``. That's what I have heard.

Answer (score 2):

"My son is studying electrical engineering" *or* "My son is pursuing an electrical engineering *degree*" *or* "My son is pursuing *a career* as an electrical engineer."

Comment: Why are "Electrical Engineering" and "Electrical Engineer" capitalized?

Comment: Following the pattern of OP, but you're right, it should be lowercase. Edited to fix.

Answer (score 1):

Some options:

> My son is studying electrical engineering in college.
>
> My son is in the electrical engineering program at so-and-so school.
>
> My son is an electrical engineering degree program.
>
> My son is pursuing an electrical engineering PhD degree.

Typically you use "pursue" for graduate degrees in this context.